# Scala/Akka JVM crashing without error after reaching ~68M instances for TreeMap elements in heap

Tags: java, docker, garbage-collection, jvm, akka

I am currently working on a platform which maintains the history of an event stream in-memory. Data is streamed into an Akka cluster where each actor (partition) maintains the history of a set of entities in the form of a TreeMap (have had trials with other collections and this seems to work the best). These actors are then instantiated within docker containers which can be deployed across the available resources.

However, once the number of historic points within all the TreeMaps (for a given container) reaches roughly 68Million, the containers crash without warning and produce no errors. This is with the container utilising <50% of the allocated RAM. It should also be noted that this appears to occur during a GC cycle which takes over 6 seconds to complete! I have run several tests on this system with different throughput and number of actors, but the same thing keeps happening when reaching this number of instances.

I have been monitoring all of the containers via Prometheus and they run consistently up until this point. For example, in the first graph below it can be seen that the number of previous states steadily increases and then flatlines. Additionally in the second graph, the average amount of messages in the mailbox is ~1 until it massively spikes at the same time. This is not due to a large increase in traffic, but instead because all threads are blocked.

[image: Number of historic points within TreeMaps]

[image: Average mailbox size for akka containers]

I have additionally been recording the memory utilisation of live instances for each container (graph three below) and this appears to drop dramatically around the same time as the spike above. This should not occur as the instances still have references and are being used within processing.

[image: Memory usage of live instances within the heap]

I have not yet tried to tune the garbage collector settings, so they are currently default. If anyone has any idea of what might be causing this or some parameters I could try tweaking that would be great.

Comment: I've just read about a similar inexplicable problem related to GC (freeing occupied memory) caused by a CPU bug. In case you're using Skylake with Hyperthreading, then try to switch it off. *Otherwise / if nothing changes, then just forget it.* The [original link](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/intel-skylake-bug/) and how I [came there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436429/crash-during-startup-on-a-recent-corporate-computer#comment788876_436430).

Comment: Cheers for posting the links here! We aren't using Skylake, though this is an interesting path of investigation. We are going to try it on a couple different servers and see what occurs. Will report back here if a solution is found.